# Locking a part of memory for multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to write some code that creates threads that can modify different parts of memory concurrently. I read that a `mutex` is usually used to lock code, but I'm not sure if I can use that in my situation. Example:

```
using namespace std;
mutex m;
void func(vector<vector<int> > &a, int b)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10E6; i++) { a[b].push_back(1); }
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<vector<int> > ints(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(thread (func, ref(ints), i % 4));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { threads[i].join(); }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, the mutex just locks the code inside `func`, so (I believe) every thread just has to wait until the previous is finished.

I'm trying to get the program to edit the 4 vectors of `ints` at the same time, but that does realize it has to wait until some other thread is done editing one of those vectors before starting the next.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you want 4 mutexes... one by `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: This is just an example I came up with. I'm trying to write code that is allowed to use the 4 different vectors I made simultaneously from different threads.

Comment: `a[b].resize(a[b].size() + 10E6, 1);` would likely be more efficient than `for (int i = 0; i < 10E6; i++) { a[b].push_back(1); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the following: (one `std::mutex` by `std::vector<int>`)

```
std::mutex m[4];
void func(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &a, int index)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m[index]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10E6; i++) {
        a[index].push_back(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So now a thread has to wait only if it tries to lock a mutex that is already locked, right? That seems to do the trick!

Comment: The thread has only to wait if it tries to modify the same `std::vector<int>` (indexed by `index`) as an other working thread.

Comment: Follow-up question if you don't mind: What would you do if you don't know the required amount of mutexes before running part of the code?

Comment: You may keep the `std::mutex` with the shared resource: something like `std::vector<std::pair<std::mutex, std::vector<int>>>`

Comment: What does the pair achieve? I'm trying to just use a 'vector<mutex>', but it won't allow me to 'push_back' mutexes into it.

Comment: `std::pair<A,B>` is basicaly a `struct {A first; B second;};`. `std::mutex` is not copyable/movable, so in fact you should replace `std::mutex` by `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>` in my precedent message.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) instead of a mutex?

The following questions might help you:

[Semaphore Vs Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319101/semaphore-vs-mutex)

[When should we use mutex and when should we use semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039899/when-should-we-use-mutex-and-when-should-we-use-semaphore)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
void func(vector<vector<int> > &a, int b)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10E6; i++) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lk(m);
        a[b].push_back(1);
    }
}
```

You only need to lock your mutex while accessing the shared object (`a`). The way you implemented `func` means that one thread must finish running the entire loop before the next can start running.

Comment: Won't this just hammer the mutex?  I mean, even if this "works" it may be a performance pessimization.

Comment: But does this let the code access the different vectors simultaneously? It seems like it just switches between iterations, placing a '1' in every vector after the other. 

I ran the code. The process uses all my cores, but it takes much longer than the example in my opening post.

Comment: properly implemented mutexes are cheap. Typically they are implemented entirely userside for cases where there is no contention and involve just executing a few assembler instructions. If you are depending on parallelization for performance reasons, keep the time you are locking mutexes to a minimum